# Extjs uses child-viewmodel data when parent-viewmodel is desired

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

Consider such snippet (which can be run at https://fiddle.sencha.com/, and at top right combobox choosing classic instead of modern):

```
Ext.define('ReusableComponent', {
    xtype: 'reusable',
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    
    config: {
        foo: 'Foo'
    },
    
    updateFoo: function(foo) {
        this.getViewModel().set('foo', foo);  
    },
    
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            foo: 'Foo'
        }
    },
    
    items: [{
        bind: {
            html: 'foo = {foo}'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.define('ConcreteComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            foo: 'Bar'
        }
    },
    
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'reusable',
        bind: {
            foo: '{foo}'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('ConcreteComponent', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'ConcreteComponent',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });
    }
});
```

The dream is to have a reusable component, which would have a defined external interface, and knowing it should be enough. Those who use that component should not have to know its internals. In this example, external interface is common config it inherits from Ext.Container (like width/height/etc), and `foo` config.

So say I then try to use it in ConcreteComponent. I know the reusable component has config foo, and thus I should be able to bind it to my own viewmodel, and that's what I do. However this doesn't work, and it shows `foo = Foo`, instead of (expected) `foo = Bar`. It seems clear why -- I **unknowingly** used name already present in the child's viewmodel, and extjs picks that instead of what I defined in ConcreteComponent. It's also clear how to bandaid-fix this (in ConcreteComponent rename viewmodel data property from `foo` to `foo2` for example). **But that forces to know internals of that reusable component, not just its public interface**. Is there anyway to solve this? Or should children viewmodels always be considered part of their public interface no matter what?

Comment: using `config` and `updateFoo` means that you are aware of namings in the reusable component, so you can just use a different name, `this.getViewModel().set('foo2', foo); ` and use foo for ConcreteComponent without worrying

Comment: [fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a6o)

Comment: well yes, config foo is explicitly public interface of the component, and anyone wishing to use it must be aware of it. Internal viewmodel data foo is not.

Comment: @LightNight in your fiddle example in the reusable component you bind to `{foo}` which isn't defined in its viewmodel. This makes reusable component's viewmodel part of public interface (since classes wishing to use it must know to provide foo in their own viewmodel), which I want to avoid. In particular, one serious issue is that you then cannot have more than one instance of reusalbe component in same component tree, since you cannot provide different `foo` for different instances

Comment: not sure what exactly you mean, can you provide fiddle example of desired code? maybe there is a route to achieve what you want. [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a6o) this does not suit your needs?

Comment: @LightNight desired code is in original question. Your second fiddle will have same issue if you rename `{foo_second}` to `{foo2}` in ConcreteComponent. You made it work by explicitly knowing to not use `foo2`, which is in reusable component's viewmodel; ie you know internals of reusable component. But my whole question is how to avoid bugs without knowledge of internals? The code using reusable component 
 (ie ConcreteComponent ) should be able to define whatever viewmodel data fields it wants, including `foo2`

Comment: @Neo Thank you, now I understand your question. will try to dig in ViewModel, if I find anything will provide an answer

Comment: If you use the bind property Ext will use lookupViewModel method to find the next viewModel - in your reuseable cmp. Your code does not update the reuseable viewModel. A hack could be something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a88

Comment: @devbnz that hack breaks intended interface. I should be able to do `{xtype: 'reusable', foo: 'bar'}` just like with any other config. This won't work with your fiddle however, because you don't use config value at all

Comment: You have defined foo as bind property in your initial post, thats a small difference. Please consult the docs how Ext evaluates this config -> https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-bind. I have changed the fiddle and it should work now, no hacks: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a8g

Comment: @hwsw I'm not sure what you mean by bind property, but configs have setter methods created for them and thus I can bind it to viewmodel (like I did it in my question); docs about it: `https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html#application_architecture-_-view_models_data_binding_-_binding_and_configs` ("Any configuration a component possesses may be bound to, so long as it has a setter method"). Your fiddle is still unsatisfactory:

Comment: 1) it only checks config on init; if I had a controller and later did `lookup('reusable').setFoo('someothervalue')` it won't work. 2) it still fails to deliver usecase with a binding to viewmodel; if I replace in your fiddle `foo: barValue` with `bind: { foo: '{foo}' }` it shows `foo = Foo` instead of desired `foo = Bar`

Comment: You pass bind as config to your reusable component, thats why you see Foo, because this bind uses the viewModel of the reusable component.  Ext will always try to use the closest model - using lookupViewModel https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-lookupViewModel. Thats why i set in my first fiddle the value to undefined, to show you that it will get bound to the parent one (Ext searches for the key somehwere else). To your first point - just implement the updateFoo method. i have updated the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a8g

Comment: @hwsw `just implement the updateFoo method` I have this in my original question. `because this bind uses the viewModel of the reusable component` I'm aware, and I know that this is the cause of the issue. My question isn't as much about why happens what happens in my snippet -- my question is: is there a work around or pattern or something that would code-wise look similar to reusable component I posted, and which could be used without knowledge that it has internally a viewmodel with specific fields.

Comment: Sorry, may someone else can help you, following LightNights, and my answers and your responses - they do not make sense to me. Simplest approach is to use html and call setHtml and / or update.

Comment: @hwsw yes, using direct setHtml here would be simplest solution. But this is only minimal example. The actual reusable component I make has alot of formulas, store proxy bindings, two way bindings, and other viewmodel niceties used. I really like the code (except for this detrimental issue), and refactoring it to work without viewmodel would make it less concise and less nice, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @hwsw I did find the solution, by browsing extjs' source code, where they use similar pattern of private viewmodel in a reusable component

Comment: @hwsw please elaborate what is unclear about my question, I'll edit it. This issue wasn't trivial to catch and solve, I'd hope to help others avoid this issue. I just got reminded of this, because I almost stepped on it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to simply create a viewmodel manually under a private property (which breaks up viewmodels' child-parent chain extjs creates between component's viewmodel and its container's viewmodel https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-viewModel), and pass it to reusable component's children explicitly via viewModel config. Using `defaults` seems to work fine. I saw the solution when stumbling upon color picker's source code https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Selector.js.html . Here is question's fixed code

```
Ext.define('ReusableComponent', {
    xtype: 'reusable',
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    
    config: {
        foo: 'Foo'
    },
    
    updateFoo: function(foo) {
        this.childViewModel.set('foo', foo);  
    },
    
    constructor: function() {
        this.childViewModel = Ext.create('Ext.app.ViewModel', {
            data: {
                foo: 'Foo'
            }
        });
        this.defaults = {
            viewModel: this.childViewModel
        };
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    
    items: [{
        bind: {
            html: 'foo = {foo}'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.define('ConcreteComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            foo: 'Bar'
        }
    },
    
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'reusable',
        bind: {
            foo: '{foo}'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('ConcreteComponent', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'ConcreteComponent',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Despite being downvoted, this is *the* answer that directly answers the original question, and it's also based on official source

Comment: Late Answer: Personally I'd use a mixin to achieve this.